# Div preview like thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want users on my site to see live preview of a div. For example, there is one big div where user is free to make any changes. I want the user to see a small thumbnail of the same div on the same page.

I tried using jquery's clone method like this -

```
$('.big').clone(true).addClass('small').appendTo("#show");
```

I am trying to clone the div with class *big* and using CSS I am making it look like thumbnail. Although it works, but it duplicates the inner div's with same id's which is affecting the functionality of my site.

I want to know if there is any better way in Jquery/Javascript to create previews of div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution

We use transformation of div using css transform.

```
var fScaleAmount = 0.5;

   DivObj.css({
    "-moz-transform": "scale(" + fScaleAmount + ")",
    "-moz-transform-origin": "0% 0%",
    "-webkit-transform": "scale(" + fScaleAmount + ")",
    "-webkit-transform-origin": "0% 0%",
    "-ms-transform": "scale(" + fScaleAmount + ")",
    "-ms-transform-origin": "0% 0%",

   });
```

Comment: Love this solution!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to change the id of the clone, to e.g. "clone" or whatever fits.

```
$('.big').clone(true).attr('id', 'clone').addClass('small').appendTo("#show");
```